# Error code 0x800704CD when generating PDF to zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, zip

I know this question was asked & answered before, but the solutions don't work for me. I have to dynamically create a list of PDFs, and each row has a checkbox. You check the PDFs you want to download, whose ID get passed to a function to create the PDF. I store those PDF's in a list, which gets passed to the Zip function (DotNetZip). Problem is, when first generating a PDF, I get that error somewhere in the middle of creating it, about halfway through, when adding a new page in the PDF. Usually it's the same spot but occasionally it changes where it crashes. Could anyone look at my code and point out where I'm messing up?

```
    protected void Download_PDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;

        String archiveName = "Arhiva Inspectii.zip";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=\"" + archiveName + "\"");

        int nr_rows = tbl_inspectii.Rows.Count - 1;

        foreach (String id_chbx in ID_Checkbox)
        {
            CheckBox chbx = tbl_inspectii.FindControl(id_chbx) as CheckBox;
            String PDF_id = "";
            if(chbx != null)
            {
                if(chbx.Checked)
                {
                    PDF_id = chbx.ID.Replace("ChBx", string.Empty);
                    Create_PDF(PDF_id);
                }
            }  
        }

        string destdir = Server.MapPath("~/Zip/") + archiveName;


        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddFiles(PDF_list, destdir);

            zip.Save(destdir);
        }

    }


    protected byte[] Create_PDF(String id_insp_max)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
                Document brosura = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                brosura.SetMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);
                PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(brosura, ms);//new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Pdf/") + titlu_pdf + ".pdf", FileMode.Create)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + titlu_pdf + ".pdf\"");
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(brosura, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                brosura.Open();

                //lots of SQL, and brosura.Add();
                //at some point, a brosura.Add() has the error halfway through the pdf

                brosura.Close();
                PDF_list.Add(titlu_pdf);
                wri.Close();

                return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That error code may suggest a bit size. I would force the project to x64 bits - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  move the Response block after you closed the Document.
And try to add Response.End();

And why are you return the Array in Create_PDF but does not using it?